# Morning seder as the "main" seder

Tags: history, torah-study, time, yeshiva-school

In most Yeshivas with which I am familiar, morning seder, the regimen of learning before lunch, is the more in-depth and intense learning seder, while afternoon seder (session) is generally less in-depth and often is designed to cover more ground.

When and how did this develop?  Is there a reason that this should be the preferred method?

Note: I am *not* interested in the plethora of literature which is bashing this system.  I am interested in the current system as it exists.

Other note: This is my personal observation of most Yeshivas.  If you want to provide documentation that this is not the norm, that is fine, but please don't answer by arguing because you "feel" differently.

Comment: People are usually the most awake in the morning and have the most energy as the day goes by the energy wears off.So main seder it makes sense

Comment: @sam It's possible.  Happens to be I am much more alert in the afternoon, and rely exclusively on coffee for morning seder.  This morning, being coffee-less, I fell asleep in morning seder.

Comment: It all depends when one goes to sleep

Comment: @sam I don't think so.  Some people are just more awake after they shake off sleep and some people wake up and are immediately alert.  I am tired when I wake up and my wife is wide awake when she wakes up.

Comment: @YEZ you specifically want to see about this Seder being in the morning, or can I respond with sources for the iyun-bekius split?

Comment: @Matt You mean sources about there being a difference between iyun-bekius?  I don't know how that would address the question.  But I am more interested in the morning/afternoon development.  When and how that came to be.

Comment: @Y  e  z my answer: it all started with Avraham avinu who with his morning prayers originated shacharit at the time of the yeshiva of Shem and Ever.